# How to insert this array into a MYSQL database and why mine won't work?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert this array into my database, using an implode statement. But i am struggling to find where I am going wrong: I basically am looking to convert the two functions below to return strings:

```
 function Titles($link) {
$str = file_get_contents($link);    
if( strlen( $str )>0 ) {    
    preg_match_all( "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $str, $titles );
    if (count($titles) > 1) {
        return $titles[1];   
    }
}

return '';
}

  function getMetas($link) {
$str1 = file_get_contents($link);    

if (strlen($str1)>0) {
    preg_match_all( '/<meta.*?name=("|\')description("|\').*?content=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', $str1, $description);
    if (count($description) > 1) {
        return $description[4];   
    }

}


 }


  $data = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
$output = array(
    "title"       => Titles($link), 
  "link"        => $link,
  "description" => getMetas($link),
  "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
   );
   if (empty($output["description"])) 
   {$output["description"] = getWord($link);
  }
   $data[] = $output;
  }
  print_r($data);  

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO scan (title, url, description, keywords) VALUES ('".implode("'),('",$data)."')");

  if (!mysql_query()) {
echo "woops";
    }

   mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: try implode("','",$data). You dont need to put individual values in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$data` is a multi-dimensional array, so after you implode, you still have arrays instead of strings in your query.

You can solve that by using `implode` earlier on `$output` as well:

```
$data[] = implode(',', $output);
```

Apart from that you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your original variables but as the `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated, you really should switch to prepared statements in mysqli or PDO.

**Edit:** Actually you need to modify both implodes:

```
 $data[] = '"' . implode('","', $output) . '"';
 ...
 mysql_query( "INSERT INTO scan (title, url, description, keywords)
    VALUES (" . implode('),(',$data) . ")" );
```

Comment: and how can I delete the 'Array' parts in my multidimensional array

Comment: it doesn't have my title or description from my array

Comment: it still won't work, it keeps returning the word 'Array' instead of title or description

Comment: @Norman Berry That means your `Titles` and `getMetas` functions return arrays. You would need to fix that first.

Comment: is there a way to convert those into strings if i show you both arrays?

Comment: @Norman Berry You need to fix the problem, not patch up the values afterwards.

Comment: above is my code for both functions, is there a way to implode the values returned??

Comment: @Norman Berry You need to `var_dump` your variables on the way to see where the problem is.

Comment: @NormanBerry use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all` in your functions `getMetas and Titles`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fields =   array_keys($data);
    $values =   array_values($data);

    $formatedValues =   array();
    foreach($values as $val)
    {   $val    =   "'".addslashes($val)."'";
        $formatedValues[]   =   $val;
    }
      $table="scan";

$sql    =   "INSERT INTO ".$table." (";
    $sql    .=  implode(", ",$fields).") ";
    $sql    .=  "VALUES( ";
    $sql    .=  implode(", ",$formatedValues);
    $sql    .=  ")";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: is there a way to implode the two returned arrays from the functions above into a string to use in my INSERT

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES( 'Array')' at line 1

Comment: @Norman Berry  print_r(links) to check whether you get proper results

Comment: will i have to implode the two function arrays or shall i just follow your code?

Comment: @Norman Berry the problem is with inserting array of values why don't you try to execute the insertion in foreach link itself,on behalf of assigning to array insert it to table.